# specify https port in play framework 2.0

Tags: https, port, playframework-2.0

How do I specify which port for Play https to start on?  In Play 1.2.4 I would add to the application.conf:

```
https.port=9443
```

But Play 2.0 does not seem to support this anymore.  Also, this syntax plainly does not work:

`play start -Dhttps.port=9443`

although this way does work for regular http: `play start 9100`

Anyone know how to do this for https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this answer on the Play! discussion group, direct https support is not available in Play! 2.0 yet:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/I7I7lULd0cI

If you need https, you can either stick with Play! 1.2.4, or put an https-capable web server in front, such as Apache or nginx.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Play 2.0 branch that supports HTTPS](https://github.com/bblfish/Play20).

[Official issue](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/215-tls-https-support-in-play-20) status is "in progress", as of time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to have HTTPS support in Play 2, it looks like it has been added.  I see it is a system property with the name "https.port" as you specified.  The change has been in there for a while now.  I think what you had tried before should work now under 2.0.3.

Here is where I found that source.  It wasn't in the docs.
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/NettyServer.scala

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it looks like it was added back in by version 2.1.

The latest docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ConfiguringHttps